# Not able to upload a New Resume on SO Jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I am trying to upload a new resume (.pdf), I get the following errors:

1. **From Computer** - Error on file upload: XHR returned response code 503

> [image: Error While Uploading through My Computer Options]

2. **From Dropbox or Google Drive** - An unknown error occurred

> [image: Error while uploading through Dropbox or Google Drive]

Flows I tried:

1. Job  -> Apply Now -> Upload Resume
2. Edit Profile & Settings -> Job Preferences -> Upload Resume

Comment: Thanks, something went boom with the virus scanner, investigating now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the nodes on our virus scanning infrastructure freaked out this morning and HAProxy didn't detect anything untoward and kept it in service. I've rebooted the box and we're looking into why HAProxy didn't take it out of rotation.

Things look to be back up and running now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I get the same issue today. I guess the problem is back? thanks

Comment: I am also receiving this error again. Looks like a virus scan node is down again?

Comment: We’re getting the machines recycled again now, should be back shortly. *Something* triggered it off again :/ will dig when back in tomorrow